# WPF: Adapt Grid to Image

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I know that in WPF images can fit a grid. Now is there also the possibility for a grid to adapt to an image?

I want to use an automatic layout to place buttons on certain positions on the image, but it is also important that the image keeps its original shape (therefore Stretch=Uniform). But when I'm working with rows and columns of a grid at first the button is right where I want it, but if I stretch my window in width but not in height the button veers away from the position I'd like it to be (based on the image).

Is it clear what I'd like to do? Does anyone have an idea how I can achieve that?

Edit:
On my image is let's say a circle and I want a button to always be near the circle.
Ok so here is the code I have so far:

```xml
<Window x:Class="VakPumpEntwurf2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid Background="#FFE62626">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="69*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="21*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="254*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="173*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="55*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="33*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="107*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="107*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image Source="images/MyPic.png" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="5" >  
    </Image>

    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>  //This Button shall be always near the circle
</Grid>
```

Here are also two pictures I hope make it clearer where exactly my problem lies:

[image: This is the position I want my button to be regarding the circle]

[image]

And this is where my button is after I stretched the width of the window. But actually I'd like my button to be always very close to the circle.

Comment: Can you give us some of your code (the parts that are necessary for this question)? SO is not a code request site ;-) you have a bigger chance of people helping you out by showing what you already made yourself.

Comment: You could put your entire UI into a `ViewBox` and set `Stretch` to `Uniform`.

Comment: If you want to maintain the same distance between the button and the circle you should consider using a Canvas panel instead of a Grid. A Canvas defines an area within which you can *explicitly* position child elements by using coordinates that are relative to the Canvas area: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: @mm8 it's worth a try, but could I still set the backgroundimage of the Canvas to Stretch=Uniform?

Comment: Sure. See my answer.

Comment: @Manfred Radlwimmer The Viewbox worked, but only without the row/column definitions of a grid. But that's ok I guess.

Comment: @Manfred Radlwimmer ok the problem I have with the ViewBox now is that my button scales together with my image. Is there a possibility to avoid that?

Comment: @MaChaToc No, that's the purpose of a ViewBox.

Comment: A `Grid` should work as well. However, it seems to me like you want to use a `Width="Auto"` instead and add `Margin`s and `HorizontalAlignment`s to your button and image. Would that work? You can also put a new grid in your grid and add both of the elements there. It's hard to give advice when you don't explain why there are so many rows and columns - i.e. should the elements be relative to *other* elements as well?

Comment: A `StackPanel` would also work if you can add both of the elements to that. [There's a bunch of containers in WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675291(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: @Default The other columns are there, so that I can put other elements there as well. It's not important to me that the elements are relative to each other, but that that the elements are positioned relative to certain points on my image

Comment: How do you want the elements to react when the window is resized? Should it be centered in the window or for instance stay put in the upper left corner?

Comment: Now if we take the picture I posted above as reference, when the window is resized and circle is getting bigger, I want the control to keep its size and keep the same distance to the circle. The circle is not a control, it is on the picture in the background

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain the same distance between the button and the circle you should consider using a Canvas panel instead of a Grid.

A Canvas defines an area within which you can explicitly position child elements by using coordinates that are relative to the Canvas area: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas(v=vs.110).aspx

> it's worth a try, but could I still set the backgroundimage of the Canvas to Stretch=Uniform?

Sure. Just set the Background property of the Canvas to an ImageBrush:

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="bg.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
    </Canvas.Background>
    ...
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, I guess the solution lies in a combination of what @mm8 and @Manfred Radlwimmer suggested.

Here is the code that worked out for me:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="337" Width="514" Background="AliceBlue">


    <Viewbox>
        <Canvas Width="200" Height="100">
            <Canvas.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="images/pic1.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
            </Canvas.Background>
            <Button Canvas.Left="30" Content="Howdy" Canvas.Top="5" FontSize="6" Width="25" Height="16"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>

</Window>
```

I have better control over the position of my button and the button is scaleable relative to my image. But as @Manfred Radlwimmer said, that is the purpose of a ViewBox. Even though a ViewBox does strange things with the dimensions of the control inside it.

Thanks everyone for their help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Lets go with some nested grids...

```
<Grid Background="#FFE62626">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Image Source="images/MyPic.png"/>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Click me 2"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The outmost grid is stretching to the parent container. The 2nd level grid is the same size as the uniform-stretched image within. The 3rd level grid is same size as second level grid and is providing a proportional row/column definition. The button is located at the upper left of the 2nd row and column of the 3rd level grid.

Honestly, I can't say why the 3rd level grid is needed instead of having the rows and columns on the 2nd level and let the image span multiple rows/columns, I just tried both layouts and only the 3 level one worked as expected.